# Why can't I store the text from a Tk text widget into a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am trying to get the user input from the text widget and store it in a variable for use later in my code

```
self.dataset = Text(master)
self.dataset.pack()

self.data = self.dataset.get('1.0', 'end')

ttk.Button(master, text="print dataset", command=lambda: print(self.data).pack()
```

When I try press the button it prints an empty string. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: It is because you are setting `self.data` about 1 millisecond after creating the widget, and well before the user has a chance to type anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bryan's comment is correct, you're getting the data very, very quickly and then never updating it from then. To solve it, since you need to reference it later, you need to use something you can `set`, like a tkinter `StringVar`; then your button command can become

```
lambda: self.data.set(self.dataset.get('1.0','end'))
```

Alternatively, since this code obviously comes from a class, you can always set your data in a function:

```
def setdata(self):
    self.data = self.dataset.get('1.0','end')
```

And your button to get that data has the command of just self.setdata; you can keep your current button and it should print the now-gotten dataset.